# HTTP Put request Android REST API

Tags: android, rest, http, authentication, put

I am fairly new to Android development, and my current task is to implement a simple login activity that verifies an email/password combination with a REST backend service. I have the layout configured, as well as the values for the EditText email and password in my activity class, but I am very stuck trying to figure out how to make the HTTP Put requests... Any help would be greatly appreciated. My class and verifyLogin are below.

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public void verifyLogin(View view) {

    EditText emailEditText = (EditText)         findViewById(R.id.editText_email_address);
    EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

    boolean loginSuccess = false;
    //URL for backend login service
    URL url = new URL("http://ENDPOINT_LOGIN_URL_HERE");
    //put request for this URL
    HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
    httpPut.addHeader("application/xml", "Content_type");
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //response from backend
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);

}
```

PS: I have done a great, great deal of Google searches and have watched videos and looked through sample code. If nothing else, a good starting point would be a great help or even a good place to look for help.

Comment: Read a book sometime.

Comment: Will do @PatMyron! Just bought a great one called "How to send push notifications without Parse." Can't wait to see what it has in store!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Apache HttpClient for Android. Android has this library inside the SDK.
There are many tutorials talking about this. Check: http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android

The basic codes are:

```html
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("your url");
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postFiledName1", "value1"));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postFiledName2", "value2"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    // then do something about the response
```

Comment: Thanks Hector, what are those parameters in the add() function where you are adding values to that list? Would mine look something like pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","password"));

Comment: For Html input form we have something like:
`<input type="text" name="email" value="hector@ventoura.com">`
`<input type="text" name="password" value="123456789">`

For the java code, it should be:
`pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",“hector@ventoura.com”)); `
`pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",“123456789”));`

Comment: Chech this tutorial:
[HttpClient Tutorial link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/)